# Почему не пишется так, как слышится?

Tags: фонетика

Задумалась: а почему вообще в русском языке часто пишется одно, а произносится другое? Конечно, в этом плане в тех же английском и французском все еще печальнее, но дело не в этом. Как вообще так получилось, что, например, пишется "крокодил", а говорится фактически "крАкАдил"? Почему письменная речь не подогнана под устную или наоборот?
Извините, если вопрос глупый.

Comment: Русский язык - это язык очень молодого народа. Некоторые правила этого языка разработаны представителями "советского народа" (цит. по преамбуле последней конституции СССР).

Comment: Слава историкам и юристам!.. Помнится, в одной из своих ярких, зажительных речей Н. С. Хрущёв призвал языковедов ввести правило: как слышится, так и пишется ("карова","малако" и т. д.). Но ему не вняли.

Comment: В детстве я говорил "малако" и писал "малако". Меня же ругали и за то, что я не писал "молоко", и за то, что произносил "молоко", пытаясь запомнить странное правописание слова "малако".

Однажды я побывал на Русском Севере, коренные жители которого говорят "молоко" и пишут "молоко". Мне очень понравились коренные жители Русского Севера. Не было в них никакого подвоха.

Затем я побывал в Беларуси, коренные жители которой и говорят "малако", и пишут "малако". Мне очень понравились беларусы.

Comment: Вот словосочетание "полевой цветок". Можно написать "палевой цветок", и кто-то подумает что он палевого цвета, мы же собирались сказать, что он растет в поле. Вы бы хотели, чтобы наша письменная речь состояла из таких ребусов? Но тогда возникает вопрос: а что же с устной речью? А там мы жертвуем частью смысла ради удобства и красоты произношения. Звук О - напряженный звук, а звук А - свободный, естественный. Мне не очень нравится звук О, но вполне устраивает буква О. У нас всего-то пять смыслоразличительных гласных, не стоит уменьшать их количество до двух-трех.

Comment: @Галактион, у Вас замечательная толерантность. Если Вы станете Президентом, у нас никогда ни с кем не будет войны (особенно, если Путин оставит Вам удачно реформированную и современно вооружённую армию): Вам нравятся все, кто не обманывает своё население и поступает строго по букве Конституции.

Comment: >Если Вы станете Президентом,  
  
Боже избави...

Comment: Что, уже сейчас видно, что наломает дров?

Comment: Галактион,  вы  смешиваете  или  не  разделяете  язык ( аудиосистему),  которая  развивается  по  своим  лингвистическим  законам,  это  предмет  учёных-лингвистов,  и  орфографию  -  систему  знаков  для  передачи  звуков.  Это  система  вторичная,  искусственная ( и  не  такая  уж  молодая - тысяча  лет  всё-таки ) - вот  она  регулируется  правилами.  Она  действительно  молодая.  Вы  сильно  не  переживайте:  если  сторонников  вашего  подхода  к  орфографии  будет  уж  очень  много,  правила  могут  и  поменяться.  Такие  попытки  были.  Могут  и  повториться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего,  хотелось бы поблагодарить автора за вопрос, который дает возможность поделиться с вами мыслями о нашей орфографии, которая совершенно удивительна и уникальна.

Действительно, почему мы пишем не так, как говорим, и  читаем не так, как написано?  Дело в том, что для этого есть важные причины, и связаны они не с погрешностью устной речи,  а напротив,  с ее орфоэпическими законами.

Попробуем рассмотреть наш вопрос  на примере слова ПОВОЗКА.  Оно состоит из 4-х морфем: ПО + ВОЗ + К + А. Это буквенная запись каждой морфемы, полностью соответствующая звуковому  (фонемному) составу. (Фонемы – это как бы смысловые кирпичики, из которых складываются морфемы).

А теперь составим из этих морфем слово, в котором появляется УДАРЕНИЕ и, соответственно, РЕДУКЦИЯ БЕЗУДАРНЫХ ГЛАСНЫХ. Мы не можем не выделить ударный слог, который является  фонетическим центром слова, и поэтому редукция гласных неизбежна в количественном отношении (по протяженности звука), но она является и качественной – вместо  смыслового звука О мы произносим звук, похожий на А.  Согласные в слове также меняются , это происходит НА СТЫКЕ МОРФЕМ  – в нашем случае мы оглушаем смысловой звук С перед глухим К. Все эти изменения связаны с удобством произношения, и все они закреплены  ПРАВИЛАМИ  ОРФОЭПИИ.

Итак,  п (Λ) в о (с) к (ъ) –  из семи смысловых звуков-фонем у нас осталось четыре фонемы, опорные для передачи  смысла слова, но, оказывается, их вполне достаточно для понимания  значения сказанного.  В то же время отражать фонетическое чередование НА ПИСЬМЕ нет оснований, так как оно связано с законами УСТНОЙ РЕЧИ.

Таким образом,  на письме мы обозначаем буквами СМЫСЛОВЫЕ звуки-фонемы, а в устной речи ЧАСТЬ ИХ заменяем  звуками с неполной различительной способностью, чтобы обеспечить УДОБСТВО ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЯ. Уникальность же русской орфографии состоит в том, что, зная законы фонетического чередования, мы можем по устной речи ВОССТАНОВИТЬ фонемный  (смысловой) состав слов и обозначить его буквами. Часть текста мы записываем  по слуху,   в то время как слабые позиции звуков, где происходит чередование, требуют проверки.

И по поводу "крокодила", в котором две гласные О являются непроверяемыми. В этом случае естественно считать, что фонемный состав слова совпадает с буквенным, при этом непроверяемые гласные контролируются по орфографическому словарю, а выбор написания делается в соответствии с традиционно-историческим принципом. Если мы обратимся к этимологии, то увидим, что это др.-рус. заимствование из греческого языка, сложение kroke (галька) + drilos (дождевой червь).

Comment: И это полуправда. Например, говорим "тэст", а пишем "тест".

Comment: Примеры, которые вы приводите, - это не орфографические, а графические написания, то есть это правило обозначения ударного звука Э буквами Э/Е. Вам бы хотелось полной ясности (как слышим, так и пишем), но обеспечить ее сложно. В исконно русских словах твердого варианта звука Э вообще не было, он произносится в заимствованных словах (тест). Навести здесь порядок практически невозможно. Вот слово приходит в язык с твердым произношением, но дальнейшая его судьба неизвестна: то ли звук Э останется твердым, то ли станет мягким, и когда все это будет. Нельзя же каждый год переписывать словари.

Comment: Любопытно, что Вы напишите о следующем: говорим "вош", пишем "вошь".

Comment: Основная проблема графических написаний  - это непарные по мягкости/твердости шипящие. Выбор гласных и Ь после них является традиционным, но хотелось бы, чтобы эти традиции были ПОЛЕЗНЫ в современном языке. Поэтому в  орфографии действует грамматический принцип, который иначе можно назвать принципом ГРАФИЧЕСКОГО СООТВЕТСТВИЯ в написании одинаковых частей речи с одинаковыми грам. значениями. Известно, что все сущ. ж. рода 3-его скл. оканчиваются на Ь, этот зрительный образ очень устойчив, и не имеет смысла искажать его из-за 4-х звуков. Поэтому сохраняется традиционное написание рожь, тишь.

Comment: А что Вы напишете о следующем: говорим "изйан", пишем "изъян"?

Comment: А почему вы говорите "йа", а пишите "я"? Написание слова "изъян" полностью укладывается в общие графические правила "Обозначение мягкости согласных и обозначение звука Й". Спорным остается вопрос об использовании двух букв Ь/Ъ в одинаковой фонетической позиции. Думаю, буквы надо оставить, так как разделительный Ъ дополнительно обозначает границу приставки и корня.

Comment: 1. Стало быть, по Вашему мнению, слово "изъян" состоит из приставки "из" и корня "ян", которые разделены "буквой" "Ъ".

2. А что Вы напишите о следующем: говорим "Росия", а пишем "Россия"?

Comment: Изъян от изъять - кстати, здесь недавно разбиралось это слово. Что касается двойных согласных, то они по слуху не могут писаться. Удвоенный согласный хорошо произносится после ударного гласного перед другим гласным (масса,ванна), а в других позициях его сложно произнести. Поэтому запись двойных согласных чисто грамматическая, она отражает морфемный состав слова.

Answer (score 5):

Говорим мы все по-разному. Если я картавлю и не могу произнести *Р*, то скажу "клокодил". Вы поймёте, о чём речь? Будет, как в известной юмореске "Доктой, у меня запой". Что лечить будете? А у него, оказывается, запор.
Морфологический принцип написания позволяет "узнать" слово в любых условиях произношения, смысл написанного передаёт единый графический образ морфем — корней, приставок, суффиксов. Если писать, как слышим, то как различить слова *леса — лиса, лук — луг, кот — код, призрел — презирал*? Таким образом, единые правила написания помогают нам понять друг друга, объединяют различные территории с оканьем, аканьем, цоканьем...

Comment: Это полуправда.

Comment: Объясните,  почему  -  полуправда ?  Если  в  русской  орфогафии  принцип  такой  -  морфологический,  а  также  традиционно - исторический.

Comment: "Если в русской орфографии ..."

Answer (score 2):

Если  говорить  кратко,  то  надо  отметить  в  первую  очередь  -  информативность  текста  при  использовании  морфологического  принципа  намного  выше,  чем  при  использовании  фонетического.  Разве,  что  пропадут  диалектные  особенности  автора,  но  в  художественном  тесте  и  это  не  проблема.  Там  это  разрешается.  А,  что касается  ЖИ - ШИ  или  ЦИ - ЦЫ,  то  правила  могут  и  поменяться,  но  тем  не  менее  эти  правила  надо  будет  учить  и  знать.  И  исключения  из  правил  всегда  будут.  Стремление  избежать  исключений - признак  искусственных  языков,  вроде  эсперанто.

Answer (score 1):

Есть язык, где почти все пишется так, как произносится.Пример(Из "Капитана Врунгеля"):

Сидела птичка на лугу, к ней подкралася корова, ухватила за ногу, птичка - будь здорова!

Перевод:

Сядзела птушка на лузе, да яе падкралася карова, схапіла за нагу, птушачка - будзь здаровая!

Это, как многие уже поняли, - белорусский язык.Хорошо так писать или не очень - не берусь судить, привыкают люди ко всему.

Comment: Я уже писал, что Хрущёв хотел "упростить" грамматику русского языка по примеру белорусского.

Answer (score 0):

С., которому скоро исполнится 6 лет, пишет [печатными буквами] так, как слышит. Например, С. записал в свой блокнот следующий стишок:

"шышка,палка,

палка,свечка,

календарь,лежыт,на,печке".

Ещё одна запись в блокноте С. выглядит так: "врут, што грейпфрут" (пробелы и запятая вставлены мной).

Также С. подарил мне клочок бумаги с надписью: "...ятьибьальубльу". Обратите внимание, что ребёнок самостоятельно смоделировал набор звуков "Я тебя люблю." с помощью тех букв и одного диакритического знака, которые он знал в то время, когда писал вышеупомянутые "хорошие слова" (цит. по С.).

Далее, я обратил внимание, что С. безошибочно печатает: 1) слово "фальга", если я прошу его напечатать "фальга", 2) слово "фольга", если я прошу его напечатать "фольга". Это не противоречит моему давнему наблюдению о том, что С. имеет хороший слух.

Вместе с тем, С. **предпочитает** печатать "в" там, где нужно печатать "ф". Например, С. предпочитает печатать "вараон" вместо "фараон", "варвор" вместо "фарфор". Дело в том, что в сознании С. существует биекция между множеством звуков и множество букв. Как следствие, С. интуитивно пытается избавиться от буквы "ф", которой не соответствует никакой отчётливый звук.

Когда С. только начинал читать рассказы, его бабушка требовала, чтобы С. произносил окончание "-ого" как "-ово" (например, в слове "мужского"), а окончание "-его" как "-ево" (например, в слове "среднего"). С. отвечал бабушке: "Не ври! Я знаю как надо читать буквы." Затем бабушка и внук ссорились.

Comment: Молодец  мальчишечка.  Мои  дошколята  тоже  писали,  как  слышали.  И  полуграмотные  тоже  так  пишут.  Понять  это  можно.  А  смысл  вашего  сообщения  в  чём ?

Comment: По моему мнению, русским:

1) следует писать: "лыко", "шыло", "жыр", "шышка", "лежыт", "шашлык", "вилка",

2) не следует писать: "лико", "шило", "жир", "шишка", "лежит", "шашлик", "вилька".

Comment: Вы предлагаете убрать все традиционные написания? Мы и так все русские традиции забыли и убрали,  а уж о древнерусской грамматике и подавно не вспоминаем .Зачем? Празднуем чужой День Святого Валентина, под него сделали день св.Февронии, о котором и не знали, скоро день сурка будем праздновать и день всех святых, т.е. Духов день.Что ж, пусть будет и ЖЫ-ШЫ, это ж так трудно выучить! А вот мне трудно забыть, я буду писать ЖИ-ШИ, я знаю о фонетике наших прадедов и забывать не хочу.

Comment: Принял к сведению, что Вы и ещё кто-то "и так все русские традиции забыли и убрали, а уж о древнерусской грамматике и подавно не вспоминаете".

Я не возражаю, чтобы Вы, "зная о фонетике" Ваших "прадедов", писали "ЖИ-ШИ".

Comment: "А вот мне трудно забыть, я буду писать ЖИ-ШИ, я знаю о фонетике наших прадедов и забывать не хочу."

И я с Вами! А жылающийе могуд апщацо друг з другам на изыке падонкафф.

Comment: 1. Вы переусердствовали, включив два "фф" в слово "падонкафф".

2. Слово "изык" можно было написать "Йазык".

3. Надеюсь, остальные ошибки Вы найдёте самостоятельно.

Comment: @жихарка, Вы сделали ошибку: в слове "абщацо" после "ц" следует поставить "а", потому что слышится так. Это же не палаццо, а глагол.

Comment: Мечта  двоечников  или  очень  не  способных  к  русскому  языку.  Бывает, конечно.  В  английском,  французком  и  в  многих  других  старописьменных  языках  такие  же,  наверно,  проблемы.  Может  им  тоже  посоветовать  использовать  фонетический  принцип ?  Язык  "падонкаф"  у  англичан,  кстати,  тоже  есть.  Будем  равняться  на  малограмотных ?

Comment: А  может  на  транскрипцию  перейдём ?  Она  ещё  точней  передаёт  произношение.